# Laravel route controller action with specific param

Tags: php, laravel, routes

im trying to create a route to a controller action with a specific parameter.
So this is what ive got so far:

```
Route::get('faq', array("as"=>"faq","uses"=>"SiteController@showPage"));
```

What i want is something like

```
Route::get('faq', array("as"=>"faq","uses"=>"SiteController@showPage","params"=>"faq"));
```

The corresponding controller action looks like that

```
public function showPage($type) {
        $page = Page::where("type", "=", $type)->first();

        return View::make("pages.page")
            ->with("title", $page->title)
            ->with("page", $page);
    }
```

The pages are saved in the database, so im trying to use only one function for that und call it with different params.

Any ideas? And i dont want to resolve it like that

```
Route::get('page/{type}', array("as"=>"faq","uses"=>"SiteController@showPage"));
```

Because otherwise the urls will look like /page/agb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do you want your URLs to look in the end?

Comment: I want the url just to look like /agb

Comment: Did you try `Route::get('{page}', array('as'=>'page','uses'=>SiteController@showPage'));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is this:

```
Route::get("/{type}", array("as" => "showPage", "uses" => "SiteController@showPage"));
```

... just make sure to define that route after other more specific routes that you dont want handled by SiteController@showPage.

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. But if i have specific other urls like /login than i have to set this route before your general rule, right? i was just wondering why it isn't possible or how it is possible to set a param beside the controller and method in a route definition.

Comment: Yes, set the general rules last. I've been looking for a solution to pass parameters to controller action earlier as well, but never found a solotion.